# Can I have a media query in the document head as well as in the CSS file?

Tags: css, media-queries

Is it possible to declare a media query in the head like so:

```
<link href="css/style-mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (max-width: 736px)" />
```

and then within style-mobile.css to declare another media query, like so:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 408px) {

   .topnav-masters {
       width: 29%;
       padding: 13px 2%;
   }

}
```

I haven't been able to find an answer to this question, and my initial experimentation seems to make me think that it cannot be done. Has anyone else come across this?

This is a weird use case, and I  usually build sites mobile-first, responsively, and don't have this issue. However, in this case, the website already had a separate mobile website and now they want it to just be responsive. I was trying to save time by just including it at the right points, so that I don't have to muck around with merging the huge CSS files together. However, there are a few CSS tweaks I need to make at other screen sizes, and that is why I am trying this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules in the [`link`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/link) elements `media` attribute are used for determining under which circumstances the referenced stylesheet should be applied at all. The `@media` rules in the stylesheet aren't affected by this in any way, other than that they might not get used of course, just like the rest of the stylesheet.

So, yes, this is possible, and it works just fine for me - fine as in works as expected, the stylesheet gets applied once the window width is `736` pixels or less, and the `@media` rule in the stylesheet is applied as long as the window width is larger than `408` pixels.

If it doesn't work for you, then you maybe did something wrong, or you are expecting something wrong, or maybe there's more to this than what you are showing here (other rules, specific browsers/versions/devices, etc).

Comment: You are correct. It does work in this way. My CSS selectors were incorrect, so what I was expecting to happen was not happening. Using other elements, I was able to make changes occur with the rules in the original post. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but it is recommended just to include it in the stylesheet when possible. Also, with a responsive design it is best to use ems.